# Response.Redirect continues to go to old URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I am taking an existing ASP.net C# webapp written by someone else and we have has to change the location of the main file.  It is a address library and when they click on a name it takes them to a profile page.

The profile page location has not changed, but the old response.redirect was written using a virtual path.
When I change the virtual path to an absolute path the webapp does not acknowledge the change and continues to redirect to the old path resulting in a 404 error.

Here is the LinkButton code in the .aspx

```
<ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="viewProfile" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"  runat="server"><%# (Eval("EmpName"))%> </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the block of aspx.cs

```
 protected void gvFinder_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "viewProfile")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                Session["EmployeeId"] = gvFinder.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();

                string name = gvFinder.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;

                string y = gvFinder.DataSourceID;

                Response.Redirect("Profile");
            }
        }
```

and here is what I changed it to, but did not result in a change.

```
 protected void gvFinder_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "viewProfile")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                Session["EmployeeId"] = gvFinder.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();

                string name = gvFinder.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;

                string y = gvFinder.DataSourceID;

                Response.Redirect("http://www.ourwebsite.com/Profile");
            }
        }
```

Is anyone familiar with how to get this to actually go to the old URL?

Comment: Have you checked if there are some http handlers involved in it, might be they are doing the redirect to old path.

Comment: The only http handlers are the ones that were made automatically by IIS when thge application was launched.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that `http://www.ourwebsite.com` is not the same as the website you're calling this from? Otherwise the path (the `Profile` part) will land you right back where you started.

Comment: Try "~/Profile" o "../Profile"

Comment: I'd recommend using Fiddler to examine the Requests and Responses being made.  You might be able to sniff out a rat in a header.

Comment: NO need to call http://www.ourwebsite.com/Profile...simply call /Profile..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options
1. http://www.ourwebsite.com/Profile is not avaible,offline or expired
2. if you have source why dont you put profile.aspx in your project root directory, if you want to save old file you can rename it to porfileold.aspx in this case you dont need to change url just redeploy and it will work fine